# rewrite rule on htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess

Hi for some reason the htaccess file is not working properly

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mallyear.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/prod/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /prod/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mallyear.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ prod/ [L]
```

so all the files are in this directory prod/ but when i enter this url
https://www.mallyear.com/landing
it shows "The requested URL /prod/landing was not found on this server."

why is this happening? Please help

Comment: Your rewrite rules are taking all requests that aren't already prefixed with `/prod/` and aren't an existing file or directory, and rewriting them to contain that prefix. For example: `GET /foo` is rewritten to `/prod/foo`, and since `/landing` probably isn't a file, and isn't being treated as a directory without a trailing slash, it's being redirected.

Comment: Without knowing your intended behavior, I cannot provide much help.